Why aren't nested `setImmediate` callbacks executed on the same tick of event loop?
According to the node.js docs about event loop:

Each phase has a FIFO queue of callbacks to execute. While each phase is special in its own way, generally, when the event loop enters a given phase, it will perform any operations specific to that phase, then execute callbacks in that phase's queue until the queue has been exhausted or the maximum number of callbacks has executed. When the queue has been exhausted or the callback limit is reached, the event loop will move to the next phase, and so on.

Consider the following piece of code:
setImmediate(() => {
  console.log("setImmediate 1");
  setImmediate(() => {
    console.log("setImmediate 2");
  });
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("setTimeout 1");
}, 2);

setImmediate(() => {
  console.log("setImmediate 3");
});

The actual output is
setImmediate 1
setImmediate 3
setTimeout 1
setImmediate 2

But I would expect it to be
setImmediate 1
setImmediate 3
setImmediate 2
setTimeout 1

My reasoning:

Schedule setImmediate for "setImmediate 1" (Check queue: ["setImmediate 1"]).
Schedule setTimeout for "setTimeout 1" (Timer queue: ["setTimeout 1"]).
Schedule setImmediate for "setImmediate 3" (Check queue: ["setImmediate 1", "setImmediate 3"]).
Execute setImmediate for "setImmediate 1" (Check queue: ["setImmediate 3"]).
Print "setImmediate 1".
Schedule setImmediate for "setImmediate 2" (Check queue: ["setImmediate 3", "setImmediate 2"]).
Execute setImmediate for "setImmediate 3" (Check queue: ["setImmediate 2"]).
Print "setImmediate 3".
Execute setImmediate for "setImmediate 2" (Queue: []).
Print "setImmediate 2".
Execute setTimeout from the Timers queue.
Print "setTimeout 1".

But in reality, after step 8, it goes to the Timers queue. So my question is, why does it skip this nested setImmediate callback in the queue and go to Timers?

I think that unlike microtasks (promise jobs), macrotasks are generally always scheduled for the next iteration of the event loop, never for the current one.

@Bergi, I can see it for the timers queue since the event loop's current time is not updated between executing individual setTimeout callbacks. When you add a new timer, it's not expired yet. Callbacks in the poll phase, on the other hand, are usually executed right away. From the docs: "Since any of these operations may schedule more operations and new events processed in the poll phase are queued by the kernel, poll events can be queued while polling events are being processed"

Oh right, though there's also a limit on poll events before it goes into the next phase to avoid starvation. Regardless, the page says "setImmediate() fires on the following iteration or 'tick' of the event loop"
